# Can KeyATM use word roots for keywords?

Tags: topic-modeling, stemming

I'm using the KeyATM package in R to characterize the relative prevalence of several topics in each document of a corpus. KeyATM treats "freedom" and "free" as different keywords and does not seem to allow the use of "free*" as way to focus on the word root when specifying the list of keywords.

Is there a way to tell KeyATM to treat all versions of "free*" as the same keyword?

(I pre-process the texts with Quanteda and the stemming functions (which use Snowball) do not effectively reduce "freedom" and other variants to "free.")